# Is it pointless to use Knex if I prefer using raw over its built-in functions?

Tags: sql, node.js, knex.js

I know Knex has various benefits, which is why I am contemplating using it for my Node application. I have used it before, and I really enjoy writing the raw queries with it. (Note: I'm still in the learning stages for Knex.) Personally, I think they make the code look slightly better than using basic SQL. It's from this point that my question stems, because maybe my preference is silly here.

I would also love opinions on the built-in functions for Knex. For people who prefer those over using raw, what do you like about them? I am aiming for consistency in my application regardless of the route I choose.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Good question. I was wondering about the same thing.

Comment: Except for migrations you could use the DB driver of your favorite DB directly. Not much benefit of having knex in the middle. Usually drivers has their own poolin mechanisms too. Actually I don't think that knex is really useful for end user application development, since it is really low level and doesn't help working with relations at all. IMO (from knex maintainer's viewpoint) knex is mostly useful for people who are developing higher level libraries / frameworks. To be really efficient with the application development learning objection.js or some other light weight ORM would be better.

Comment: As a personal perspective, I'd much rather use a query builder for some projects than be saddled with an ORM. My SQL is fairly good thanks to "growing up" before either ORMs or QBs were in common use, but I don't typically reach for raw SQL as a first line tool. I think Knex has a nice little niche in the "small-ish projects with small-ish teams" category, in addition to its use in scaffolding other libraries. An interesting sideline is its usefulness in teaching students about databases without having to teach them SQL, an approach I've seen work rather well in practice.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you define as "small-ish projects"? It could be relative; what's small to one person may not be small to another. I ask because I hope for my project to be pretty large-scale with thousands of users. I would like to work smarter now so as to avoid unnecessary issues in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not pointless. It depends a bit on whether you're working in a team environment, who else is likely to have to maintain it, and how comfortable they are with writing SQL queries. Note that many things that can be done with Knex can also be done with a direct database driver, so as with many technology choices it comes down to personal/team preference and ease of maintenance.

Even assuming you never use the query builder, Knex offers:

- relatively simple configuration according to the current `NODE_ENV`
- connection/pool management
- easy parameterisation
- easy transactions
- easy migrations and seeding

Why not use `.raw`? Well it's taster's choice, and query builders aren't for everyone. However, query builder fans will tell you:

- it can be easier to migrate between database backends when you're not dealing with a bunch of raw SQL
- many people find Knex syntax easier to read, given the population of people who can reasonably understand a JavaScript promise chain likely outweighs those who grok SQL
- it tends to be rather more compact
- it provides a level of name/syntax safety (and transpile-time type safety and editor support if you're using TypeScript) over `.raw`.

Query builders also lend themselves nicely to composition, so the likes of:

```
const userPhoneNumbers = knex('users').select({ id, email });

// later...
const gmailUsers = userPhoneNumbers.where('email', 'ilike', '%gmail.com');

// still later...
return gmailUsers.where('email_confirmed', true);
```

A contrived example, but it can be quite expressive when dealing with less trivial requirements.

Comment: A lot of this stuff is pretty easy to do directly with db drivers too (at least with some db drivers). Anyways +1 for the good answer.

Comment: Yep fair call, I'll drop a note in.

Comment: @RichChurcher great comment, I appreciate your input, especially in terms of the built in functions. I'm gonna give them a try -- worst case scenario, I undo it if it turns out not to be my taste.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a little older but I agree with the hybrid approach.  There are certain situations where the query builder syntax provides good feedback for a "bad" query being written which is great.

On the opposite side, I have some queries that I think would just become too verbose written using the builder so I use `.raw`.  Here is an example of a query that I would consider as keeping in the `.raw` format.

```sql
    select
    s.client_id,
    s.package_id,
    p.products as pp,
    s.products as sp
    from (
      # grouped subscribed products
      select
      client_id,
      package_id,
      group_concat(product_id order by product_id) as products
      from subscriptions where package_id is not null
      group by client_id, package_id) as s
    inner join (
      # grouped package products
      select
      package_id,
      group_concat(product_id order by product_id) as products
      from package_products
      group by package_id) as p
    on p.package_id = s.package_id where p.products <> s.products
    order by s.client_id
```

I could certainly use the builder but I find the raw SQL a lot easier to grasp with nested selects.  I also create an abstract class to simplify down into a micro-ORM.

```js
class Table {
  constructor() {
    // nothing
  }

  static tableName = null;

  /**
   * Find by id
   * @param {Integer} userId
   * @return {Promise}
   *
   * Example:
   * Table.findById(id).then(result => {
   *   console.log(result)
   * }).catch(err => {
   *   console.error(err);
   * })
   */
  static findById(itemId) {
    return this.findOneBy({id: itemId});
  }

  /**
   * Generic findBy
   * @param {String|Object} column or objcet with keys
   * @param {Any} value
   */
  static findOneBy(column, value = null) {
    return this.findBy(column, value).then(results => {
      return results[0];
    });
  }

  /**
   * Generic findBy
   * @param {String|Object} column or objcet with keys
   * @param {Any} value
   */
  static findBy(column, value = null) {
    return database.getConnection().then(conn => {
      const schema = this.schemaName;
      const query = conn.select().from(this.tableName);
      if (schema){
        query.withSchema(schema);
      }
      if (typeof column === 'object '&& !Array.isArray(column) && value === null) {
        for (const col in column) {
          query.where(col, column[col]);
        }
      } else {
        query.where(column, value);
      }
      return query;
    });
  }
}
```

This allows me to create models by using:

```js
class Client extends Table {
  static tableName = 'clients';
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

Client.findById(1).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
}).catch(console.error);
```